# No Such Method Exception - using Reflection

Tags: android, exception, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection (on an android app) to invoke a method and it work only when I do it this way

```
Object impresora     = loadedClass.newInstance();
Object args[]        = {"00:15:0E:E0:DD:38", true};

for(Method m : impresora.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
    if("BTConnection".compareTo(m.getName()) == 0)
         int resultado = (Integer) m.invoke(impresora, args);
```

But I don't want to iterate everytime, so I'm trying this way, but this is where I get the NoSuchMethodException

```
Method m = impresora.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("BTConnection");
m.invoke(impresora, args);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your second snippet, getDeclaredMethod takes 2 arguments and not one, would be helpful if you include the actual code

Comment: I've given my answer. Hopefully that works. You need the parameter in order to try finding the method

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet you're doing `object.getClass()` in your second snippet you're doing `impresora.getClass()`.

Comment: sorry that was cause I was trying to make it more readable, but now I put the actual code

Answer (score 0):

You need the actual parameter types in order to find the methods otherwise it will try to look for the method without an argument which I am guessing doesn't exist in your class.

Seeing:

`Object args[] = {"00:15:0E:E0:DD:38", true};`

I am guessing that the first argument is a String and second one is a boolean, so in order to find the method you need to do the following:

```
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("BTConnection", String.class, Boolean.class);
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, the parameters are not the problem cause I tried with methods that don't need them

Comment: is it possible for you to put up the class where the method is in your question so we could try it out?