# NoSuchMethod Exception while using reflection api in Android

Tags: android

I have 2 classes in my android app. `Class1` and `Class2`. I have some methods in class2 which i want to invoke using reflection API.

To invoke "printString" of class2, i am using following code:

```
public void printString(String str) {
        Log.d("TAG", "in printString" + str);
    }
```

Reflection Code:

```
Method method = Class2.class.getMethod("printString");
method.invoke("asjdhaskdf", null);
```

But using this code is throwing following exception:

```
10-26 16:10:16.931: W/System.err(25036): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: printString []
10-26 16:10:16.931: W/System.err(25036):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-26 16:10:16.931: W/System.err(25036):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
10-26 16:10:16.931: W/System.err(25036):    at com.sample.mobile.android.ui.activities.Class1Activity$1.onClick(Class1Activity.java:56)
10-26 16:10:16.931: W/System.err(25036):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
10-26 16:10:16.931: W/System.err(25036):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
10-26 16:10:16.936: W/System.err(25036):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-26 16:10:16.936: W/System.err(25036):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-26 16:10:16.936: W/System.err(25036):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 16:10:16.941: W/System.err(25036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
10-26 16:10:16.941: W/System.err(25036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 16:10:16.941: W/System.err(25036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-26 16:10:16.941: W/System.err(25036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:986)
10-26 16:10:16.941: W/System.err(25036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753)
10-26 16:10:16.941: W/System.err(25036):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please advise what i am doing wrong. I have read tutorials available on internet but nothing worked.

**Update 1**

***One Imp Point: My code never reached on "method.invoke" line. It throws an exception on the line where i am getting the method using "getMethod" function.***

Code of Class2:

```
package com.sample.mobile.android.utils;

public class Class2{

    public void printString(String str) {
       Log.d("TAG", "in printString" + str);
    }

}
```

Code of class1Activity:

```
package com.sample.mobile.android.ui.activities;

public class Class1Activity extends Activity {

    private Class2 obj; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        obj = new Class2();
        Class cls;
        try {
            cls = Class
                    .forName("com.sample.mobile.android.utils.Class2");

            Method[] methods = cls.getMethods();
            Log.d("TAG", "length -- " + methods.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                Log.d("TAG", "name -- " + methods[i].getName());
                // this is printing the name of all  methods including "printString".
            }

            Method method = cls.getMethod("printString");
            method.invoke(obj, "asjdhaskdf");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because there is no such method ... you're trying invoke this method on String class ... it should be `method.invoke(instanceofClass2, "asjdhaskdf")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it because there is no such method

you're trying invoke this method on String class

it should be `method.invoke(instanceofClass2, "asjdhaskdf")`

**EDIT:** to match Update 1

... and since `printString` has String parameters you should use `getMethod` like this:

```
Method method = Class2.class.getMethod("printString", String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks man.. it is working now.. I also found the same ans from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327672/no-such-method-exception-using-reflection

Comment: i didnt notice that first time coz first what i saw was the invoke problem :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs of [Method.invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29), the first parameter is the object on which you would like to invoke the method, so in your case, you are trying to invoke `printString` on the `String` class, which doesn't exist.

I think you meant to use:

```
Class2 myObject = new Class2();
Method method = Class2.class.getMethod("printString");
method.invoke(myObject, "asjdhaskdf");
```

Comment: Hey, i tried the way you have mentioned in your answer. Please check my code in my as "update1". Can you please have a look?